# geballte Weiblichkeit, geballte Frauenpower, etc

Tags: translation

I've came across the adjective *geballte* as qualifier to nouns related to womanhood (*Weiblichkeit*, *Frauenpower*, etc.) more often than I would have expected from its straight-up meanings (*concentrated*, *clenched*).  This makes me wonder: Is there a special meaning to this particular association between *geballte* and women?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That seems to be a random observation and is not true.

*geballt* is very probably derived from the term "geballte Faust" and means "to form a ball", which can be figuratively understood as "conglomerated to hit" - So nothing to do with women in particular.

You could just as well read a motor magazine or [advertisement](https://www.audi-mediacenter.com/de/pressemitteilungen/geballte-kraft-aus-fuenf-zylindern-der-audi-rs-q3-performance-5471) and find

> geballte Kraft aus 5 Zylindern

or Book titles like "[Geballte Kraft"](https://www.amazon.de/Geballte-Kraft-Hans-Dominik-ebook/dp/B077G53T85) (a history of electricity by popular German science / science fiction author *Hans Dominik*).

There are also combinations with "Zorn" like in

> Bei einer Revolution trifft der geballte Zorn der Unterdrückten die Mächtigen.

Answer (score 2):

In my (non-scientific) observation, in these cases the adjective *geballt* suggests some sort of feminist context. However, in my opinion, the phrases *geballte Weiblichkeit* and *geballte Frauenpower* are quite overused and dull (I hope, this is the correct word in English for what I mean ;-) ).

Answer (score -2):

No. I guess it's more prevalent for describing teams of women than teams of men. Because "teams" of men tend to be less tight and with well-defined and well-defended competence areas. So there's not much *Ballung* in men teams.

(Did you know? *Team* is a German acronym. It means ***T***oll, **e**in **a**nderer **m**achts!)

Comment: a) Wieso setzt Du **teams** in Anführungsstriche, wenn es um männliche Teams geht? Meinst Du damit Pseudoteams oder was? b) Gibt es Quellen, die die Hypothese stützen, dass männliche Teams weniger eng sind oder wie kommst Du zu dieser überraschenden Aussage? Gibt es dazu empirische Untersuchungen?

Comment: Überraschend? Mich überrascht es eher, dass du offensichtlich schonmal in einem Männer-Team gearbeitet hast, in dem es starke Kompetenzüberschneidungen, aber keine ständigen Kämpfe gab. Das muss sehr eingespielt gewesen sein.

Comment: Ich stimme @userunknown zu, das hängt nach meiner Beobachtung nicht unbedingt am Geschlecht. Ich arbeite seit gut einem Jahr mit einem Männerteam, dass ausgesprochen harmonisch ist. Und die Stutenbissigkeit unter manchen Frauen ist auch nicht zu unterschätzen.

Comment: a) Ob ich selbst schon in solchen Teams gearbeitet habe oder nicht sollte unerheblich sein, da ich nicht zwingend ein typischer Fall bin. Es genügt völlig von Bergsteigerteams oder Schiffsbesatzungen zu wissen, die ohne engen Zusammenhalt gar nicht funktionieren würden. b) Steht eine Erklärung zu den "teams" noch aus.